# Gap at bottom of Nav

Tags: html, css, wordpress, themes

I'm using a drop down on my nav, and my main UL has a gap missing on browsers other than Firefox.

With Firefox, it lines up perfectly.  With IE (10) and Chrome (latest) it has a 1px gap.

Here is how my header is setup.. if anyone can help, that would be greatly appreciated.

*Note: My header is a fixed header*

```
    <!-- Begin Header -->
    <header role="banner">
        <div class="wrapped">

            <!-- Logo -->
            <a href="<?php echo home_url(); ?>" id="logo"><img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/images/logo.jpg" alt="" /></a>

            <!-- Main Menu -->
            <nav>


                <?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'menu' => 'Main Navigation')); ?>
            </nav>

        </div>
    </header>
    <!-- End Header -->
```

and my css:

```
/* Header Information
-----------------------------------------------------------------*/

header {
    width: 100%;
    height: 64px;
    background: #1c6e86;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #16586b;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 3px 2px rgba(36, 86, 104, 0.5);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 3px 2px rgba(36, 86, 104, 0.5);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 3px 2px rgba(36, 86, 104, 0.5);
    z-index: 990;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}

#logo a {
    display: block;
    float: left;
}




/* Navigation 
-----------------------------------------------------------------*/
nav {
    float: right;
}

nav ul ul {
    display: none;
}

    nav ul li:hover > ul {
        display: block;
    }


nav ul {
    margin: 21px 0 0 0;
    background: #1c6e86; 
    list-style: none;
    position: relative;
    display: inline-table;
}
    nav ul:after {
        content: "";
        clear: both;
        display: block;
    }

    nav ul li {
        float: left;
    }
        nav ul li:hover {
            background: #1f4d5e;
        }
            nav ul li:hover a {
                color: #fff;
            }

        nav ul li a {
            display: block;
            padding: 10px 15px;
            color: #fff;
            text-decoration: none;
        }


    nav ul ul {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        background: #1f4d5e;
        position: absolute;
        top: 100%;
    }
        nav ul ul li {
            float: none; 
        }
            nav ul ul li a {
                padding: 10px 20px;
                color: #fff;
            }   
                nav ul ul li a:hover {
                    background: #123440;
                }
```

--EDIT--

In browser HTML view:

```
<nav>
    <div class="menu-main-navigation-container">
        <ul id="menu-main-navigation" class="menu">
            <li id="menu-item-24" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom current-menu-item current_page_item menu-item-home menu-item-24"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li id="menu-item-171" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children menu-item-171"><a href="#">Projects <i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i></a>
                <ul class="sub-menu">
                    <li id="menu-item-21" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-21"><a href="#">WordPress Themes</a></li>
                    <li id="menu-item-22" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-22"><a href="#">WordPress Plugins</a></li>
                    <li id="menu-item-172" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-172"><a href="#">Future Projects</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li id="menu-item-188" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children menu-item-188"><a href="#">Tuts  <i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i></a>
                <ul class="sub-menu">
                    <li id="menu-item-183" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-183"><a href="#">WordPress</a></li>
                    <li id="menu-item-182" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-182"><a href="#">jQuery</a></li>
                    <li id="menu-item-181" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-181"><a href="#">HTML &amp; CSS</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li id="menu-item-187" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-187"><a href="#">Our Blog</a></li>
            <li id="menu-item-189" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-189"><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

I will eventually be removing the DIV container, as it serves no purpose.  I didn't notice that I forgot to remove it via the nav_menu call..

**and I forgot to mention the gap is a 1px gap AT THE BOTTOM of the menu** between the navigation area, and the 1px border.

Comment: I think it would be easier to troubleshoot if you pasted the source from when you are visiting the site in your browser so that the php code executes. At the moment, we can not see the ul, li, etc from your nav menu. Have you tried using reset CSS rules to see if the gap disappears?

Comment: I use a css reset that I use in ALL of my themes.. I don't like the fact that I am using a top-margin to bring the navigation down, due to it opening the possibility for incompatibility issues like this. Edit above will show the actual code from the HTML view.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
nav ul li {
    float:left;
    margin-left:-1px;
}
```

Comment: The problem isn't with the 'left', it's with the bottom.. and it's a px too short.  So adding an additional 1px would fix it in IE and Chrome, but would mess it up in Firefox..